# Error in Uploading the last chunk of file - Google Drive Python API

Tags: python, file-upload, google-drive-api

I am using Google Drive API for uploading the csv/xlsx file into my drive folder. It is working fine for smaller files but with larger files it was throwing error.

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.http import MediaFileUpload

class GoogleAPI:

    def __init__(self):
        self.service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file('media/google_service_account_creds.json', scopes = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"]))

    def GetFileInfo(self, fileId, infoFields):

        response = self.service.files().get(fileId = fileId, fields = infoFields).execute()

        print(response)

        return response

    def SearchFolderDrive(self, fileMimeType, fileName, parentFolder):

        if fileMimeType == None and fileName == None:

            response = self.service.files().list(q = f"parents = '{parentFolder}'").execute()

            return response.get('files', [])
        
        response = self.service.files().list(q = f"mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet' and name = '{fileName}' and parents = '{parentFolder}'").execute()

        for file in response.get('files', []):

            if file.get('name') == fileName:
                print(f"{file.get('name')} {file.get('id')}")
                return file

        return None

    def CreateFolderDrive(self, fileName, parentFolder):

        response = self.SearchFolderDrive('application/vnd.google-apps.folder', fileName, parentFolder)

        if response:
            return response

        file = self.service.files().create(body = {
            'name' : fileName,
            'mimeType' : 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder',
            'parents' : [parentFolder]
        }).execute()

        return file

    def UploadFileDrive(self, fileName, fileMimeType, parentFolder, filePath):

        response = self.SearchFolderDrive(fileMimeType, fileName, parentFolder)

        if response:
            print('Existing File', response)
            request = self.service.files().update(
                fileId = response.get('id'),
                body = {
                    'name' : fileName,
                    # 'parents' : [parentFolder]
                },
                media_body = MediaFileUpload(
                    filePath,
                    chunksize=1024*1024,
                    mimetype = fileMimeType,
                    resumable = True
                )
            )

        else:
            request = self.service.files().create(
                body = {
                    'name' : fileName,
                    'parents' : [parentFolder],
                    'mimeType' : 'application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet' ,
                },
                media_body = MediaFileUpload(
                    filePath,
                    chunksize=1024*1024,
                    mimetype = fileMimeType,
                    resumable = True
                )
            )

        response = None
        while response is None:
            status, response = request.next_chunk()

            if status:
                print(f'Upload {status.progress() * 100}')
```

I tried adding the chunksize parameter in MediaFileUpload(). It is running successfully but when it tries to upload the last chunk of data, it is throwing 400 error. I tried changing the size of the chunk, but it still does not work.